# Find contour without negative area inside shape

Tags: opencv

As a follow-up question to [finding contiguous black pixels in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317579/find-contiguous-black-pixels-in-image/57317834#57317834), I use OpenCV's `findContours()` to detect shapes of black on white (I invert the colors for the function to work better). In the images below, OpenCV detects the outer shape of the "g" and the inner bowl as different shapes:

[image: Detection of outer shape of "g"]
[image: Detection of inner shape of "g"]

I could use the hierarchy to discard shapes inside other shapes, but I would rather avoid it in case OpenCV detects an overarching contour around the whole image. Does `findContours` have some tuning that cause it to find only contiguous pixels and not the inside negative shape?

Comment: Do you mean `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` flag? This will only find the outer contour, but in your case it may find the background on which is even more external. Or you mean the whole black part of the g and not only the contour? then maybe [connectedComponents](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.7/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a) is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, it was `connectedComponennts` that I was looking for. I just refactored my code and it's a lot cleaner, namely because I don't deal with the hierarchy of contours. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: I missed this feature of connected components when I read the tutorial on the watershed transformation. I refactored the code from 200 lines to 120 thanks to this method and is a lot more robust.

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you. I will write the answer on the weekend  to put in more details :)